# Sytemd service fails when rebooting system using C reboot API

Tags: c, linux, systemd

I am making a C++ program that creates a sytemd service file dynamically. This service executes a script on reboot. This script is also dynamically created and it deletes certain files, disables and deletes the service and then deletes itself.
My service is something like this:

```
[Unit]
Description = Run script on Reboot
Before = 
[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/var/tmp/myscript
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And my script is:

```
rm -rf files
systemctl disable myservice.service
rm -f /etc/systemd/system/myservice.service
rm -f /var/tmp/myscript
```

After creation of the script and service, the program reboots the system using `reboot` API, passing `LINUX_REBOOT_CMD_RESTART` as parameter. However, my service fails after reboot and the files don't get deleted. I have even added the `sync` API before the reboot.
I have tested that service on its own, manually creating it and then manually rebooting the system, in that case, it works as intended. I even tried replacing the reboot API with

```
system("init 6")
```

And that too gives expected results. So, why is the `reboot` api in particular giving problem? what does that API do extra that can affect the service? I also have observed that there is some delay between the API call and the reboot starting, while calling `system("init 6")` has very less delay, almost starts reboot instantly.
What does the reboot do that could interfere with the service, and would passing some other  parameter make behave same way as `init 6`?
Also, I am executing the program in sudo mode, hence the init command doesn't have extra sudo

**Edit:** I also tested out other reboot commands using the `system` C api. I tried `system("reboot")` and `system("systemctl reboot")` and both of them are working, the service runs fine on using them. So, the issue is only caused on using the `reboot` C Api. So, are there some differences in the api and that command? does the API do something extra that could interfere with the service?

Comment: Forgive the obvious, but when you create `/var/tmp/myscript` do you make it executable? (e.g. `chmod +x /var/tmp/myscript`)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin yes, it has executable permission added in the code itself. as I said, it works totally fine with `init 6`